# Formatting Python string output

Tags: python, string, fonts, formatting, font-size

I'm writing a calculator currently and I'd like to have results displayed in a visually appealing form. The program just has a command line interface for the moment, but I've been trying to find a way to do various things with the results it displays. For example, I'd like to have it display the result in a bigger font size, a different font than system default, and even subscripts and superscripts. From what I could find, the best way to do such things would be if I introduced a GUI and used something like wxPython, and using Unicode code points can only resolve part of the issue. Moreover, for various reasons, I'd just like to have the program in command line for the moment.

Comment: Should you decide to write a GUI for this, I prefer and recommend PyQT4 over wxPython and Tkinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish this with the command line, but you might check out [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html).  I would suggest picking up a GUI for this sort of thing.  It's really not too hard to learn and Python's builtin Tkinter is perfectly functional for getting started.  There are many good resources for Tkinter.  Here are a few I like:

- [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)
- [Thinking in Tkinter](http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net/)
- [An Introduction to Tkinter](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/)

WxPython is excellent, but if you are just getting started my suggestion would be to start with Tkinter.  Others might disagree...

**EDIT**
I just remembered running across the [console](http://effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm) module for Windows.  I suspect it won't won't get you what you want, but at least it's out there.

Comment: (+1) On that note, consider [easyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/). It's a wrapper around Tkinter that makes life easier if you are writing a very simple gui.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on the command line, I'm almost certain that there's nothing you can do to override the font preferences set by the user. In both windows and Linux, the font settings of the command line are user controlled, and I doubt that you can change it without `sudo` access. Seeing as you're writing a calculator, I don't think a user would want to run it as `sudo` - I certainly wouldn't want to run something as simple as a calculator with `sudo` privileges. To require that would make the user think that you are up to something malicious